# Can I use the height of one div to implement the height of another?

Tags: html, css

Well, I tried to put a div in 100% height. I read some tutorials and I made this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

And it's going well.  The div that I wanted changed to 100% height, but the scroll bar appears. And this is because I have a menu div. If I don't have this menu div, my other div is going to be 100% height with no scroll bars.

The question is: How do I "ignore" the sizes (height) of the menu so that the scroll bars don't appear? Maybe I should use the "clear:" field?

Comment: You should include your html.

Comment: Yeah, if you post the html of the `div` and menu we might be able to provide you more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long a the menu is in the page `flow`, his height won't be ignored.

What you may want to do though, is using absolute or fixed positioning on the menu so it hoes out and your main element take all height without being pushed down by the menu.

Comment: Thank you dude, change my position "relative" to "absolute" the scroll bar desapears.

Comment: That would be a very bad practise to change the positioning just for the scrollbars. Especially position absolute is something you'll most likely regret later.

Comment: Depends on the need, but with as little detail as we had in the original question, that really seems like what he looked for. Of course, there's other solution like using table display or using lastest CSS3 layout methods - but that's a lot harder to grasp for a beginner. None the less, position absolute brings a solution which can be somehow elegant and easy to understand. But CSS is tricky, so like always, one must be carefull about the implication of their choices.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable scrollbars you should use:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to `min-height` to avoid scroll bars

```
html {
   min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```